# Convert Base64 image back to binary to write a file

Tags: javascript, image

I've been working on an Image Caching system for my mobile application, and currently it's receiving a base64 image from my server, and saving that base64 encoding in a text file. Whenever the image needs to be used the file is loaded, and the `<img src=''>` is set to the base64 encoding text that was inside of the file.

I'm wondering if it's possible, to instead of saving the files as `img.txt` and having base64 encoding inside of them, if I can take the base64 encoding, convert it back into binary, and write it into the file as text.

Something like this:

```
var image   = getBase64FromServer();
var dir     = FileSystem.dataDirectory + "image.jpg";
var text    = getBinary(image);
var replace = true;

FileSystem.writeFile(directory, text, replace).then(function(success) {
    console.log("File created");
}, function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating file: " + error);
});
```

This way I can just set my `<img src=''>` to something like this:

```
<img src="file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/x/Library/NoCloud/image.jpg">
```

and have it load, opposed to using the larger base64 alternative.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata , https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746 . Another option would be to set `img` `src` as `objectURL` , if requirement is to not set `src` as `data URI` string

Answer (score 0):

Take a loot at [WindowBase64.atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob)